# How to deal with floats in AngularJS expressions

Tags: angularjs

Is there a possibility to deal with float values in AngualrJS expressions?
I have tried this but it does not work:

```
<td>{{parseFloat(account.price).toPrecision(12) * parseFloat(account.hours).toPrecision(12) }}</td>
```

Comment: I wasn't even aware of "formular" as a word, but they are typically called "expressions" in Angular.

Comment: Please do [edit] your post to include what you mean by "does not work". Namely, what is it doing that you don't want it to and/or what it is not doing that you want it to.

Comment: angular expressions are not JavaScript;  for this to work, you would have to have a `$scope.parseFloat`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{{ number_expression | number : fractionSize}}
```